# Why is there no output from Alpha Vantage UK stock APIs?

Tags: api, alpha-vantage

Alpha Vantage UK stock APIs suddenly returned no data last week. I have tried variants such as SSE and SSE.L, with no luck.
Does anyone know why or have a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's an issue with their API. No ideas when it comes back. I've found several comments like "This is a known issue. We apologize for the inconvenience."

Upd. As a workaround you can try using Yahoo Finance API (https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/yahoo-finance1/details). There are variety of "How to use it" code snippets for different programming languages.

Best